# how IORESOURCE_IRQ(address) work in soc chip?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

We can read register map in ic spec and we can find out that there are some adress for interrrupt.
And we register the on-chip controller's interrupt, like usb controller...etc, we use the resource type to register the interrupt handler. If we check the information in proc/interrupts,  we can see the interrupt type is GIC (generic interrupt controller).

How does the interrupt work? Is this like the GPIO interrupt? Why the address can represent an interrupt signal? Does this mean the system map the gpio/address to interrupt number?
I'd like to know the detail about this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to share this.

'Cause I just work on embedded device with PowerPC, MIPS core, so I will not talk about x86, sorry.

The interrupt signal is generally triggered by the module controller, say, SD controller, UART controller, SPI controller, and the like.

As you know, the signal indicates there is an event happening on that device, and it needs CPU's attention.

On the chip, there is generally a interrupt processing module, to which interrupt signals from kinds of controllers will be sent.

Usually, there are more than one signal pins into the interrupt processing module, but, in common case, only one pin out of that module to CPU core.

If the interrupt signal pin is used just by only one device, or say, one controller, we can say that interrupt is not shared.
The reason we refer to shared interrupt is its handling flow is not the same with unshared interrupt.

Even if there is one interrupt present, and has been sent to core, it's not handled if there is no software willing to service it.

So, during the system's bootstrapping or initialization, in common, there will be a block of codes in each module, mainly device module, which will take charge of irq's initialization, such as, calling request_irq().

what request_irq() exactly does is to attach the softare to some interrupt signal, in this way, the relationship between hardware interrupt signal and software ISR is set up.

By calling request_irq(),the system is told that there is somebody who wants to take care of that event, and if that event happens, the system will make that person know by calling the function which is passed to request_irq() with the irq number.

By the way, I'm not very clear when you say "there are some adress for interrrupt".
Could you give more details?

Comment: .name = "hdmi_irq", .start = HDMI_IRQ, .end = HDMI_IRQ, .flags = IORESOURCE_IRQ, the define in linnux, the HDMI_IRQ, it defines in spec may be some address, like 0xcc0000...

Comment: your reply is very useful, thanks! About the adress for interrupt, i guess i misunderstood about the code and spec. Please ignore it.:)

Comment: If you like, please give some details about what the spec says.
I am just very curios about that. 'Cause I am just a newbie in Linux world, so please corrent me, if there are errors lying in my post.